# determine file simularity between a few sets of 25k files each

Tags: git, file, machine-learning, similarity

The [git-scm](http://ports.su/devel/git) lets you determine renames on the fly of the files stored in the same repository (e.g., [`git diff --find-renames`](http://mdoc.su/f/git-diff)).

What if I have about a dozen sets of files (e.g., about 10 sets in total (which may be independent branches of some somewhat-related software, e.g., *BSDs)), with about 25k files in each set.  (Each set may be updated daily, and represents a checkout with no history.)

Given **a file from *one set***, I'd like to know what is the likely **ancestor or descendant file (or files) in *another set***.  (Note that git itself is thus not involved at all, other than to illustrate the concept.)

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging `git` might actually make sense here.  For example, commit each file set as a separate branch of a repository.  Then, you can do something like:

```
git diff -C --diff-filter=RC --name-status proj2..proj1
```

Which will produce output like:

```
R075       file2        file1
```

If `file2` in `proj2` is 75% similar to `file1` in `proj1`.

Comment: Do you know if it's actually going to work, if there is effectively no one common ancestor for each branch, other than just empty space?  (E.g., FreeBSD is not based on OpenBSD, and neither is OpenBSD based on FreeBSD.)

Comment: do you have any more suggestions?  i'm getting a lot of false-positive reports; i'd like to ensure there are absolutely no false-positives, e.g., either the filenames must be unique enough between the two projects and match each other, or a great deal of similarity must be apparent.

Comment: I guess I might as well just do matching based on filenames alone; but thanks for the git suggestion!  BTW, I also had to do `git config --local diff.renamelimit 99999` for it to work.

Comment: You can certainly filter the output you get from the `git` command to only accept a similarity level higher than some threshold (or maybe use the `-M` flag).  Likewise you can filter that output for matching names.  TBH I don't really understand your goals regarding finding ancestors if you don't have history to look through so I'm not sure how great your results are going to be..

Comment: The idea is that some drivers/frameworks/utilities originate with one project, and get copied to another; sometimes files are split, sometimes renamed, sometimes merged; i'd like to provide a web interface (e.g., on BXR.SU) to make it possible for the viewer to see the "copies" of the file he's viewing for system X in systems Y, Z and W.

Comment: It seems like there's also a lot of false-positives with git on small files due to the licence header -- e.g., `R062    OpenBSD-sys-dev/mii/urlphyreg.h FreeBSD-sys-dev/xen/xenpci/xenpcivar.h` http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/dev/mii/urlphyreg.h http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/sys/dev/xen/xenpci/xenpcivar.h